# RubyMine (IntelliJ) is showing different indentation locally and on GitHub

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, rubymine, intellij-14

This is how my code looks in my editor:

[image: How it looks in my editor]

This is how my code looks on GitHub:

[image: How it looks on GitHub]

Here's my preferences on RubyMine:

[image: My preferences for RubyMine]

I'm using RubyMine on Mac. I just reinstalled it (because of an unrelated issue) and now it's doing this. V 2020.3

I've done quite a bit of googling and have tried playing around with settings people have suggested but nothing has worked.

Comment: Is that a `Tab` or a `Space` used for indentation? You can enable Show Whitespaces option for that file to see that (via View menu .. or via editor gutter context menu) If it's a tab and with your settings for tab side =2 .. then you may have `.editorconfig` file there that has own settings (settings from there will override IDE settings; the nature of such files). Check the status bar as well -- it should have a section for that as well.

Comment: Ah yes this is so helpful. Enabling show whitespaces showed that I was using tabs in the offending files, and spaces in the file that were fine. I don't have an `.editorconfig` file but importing a colleagues scheme resolved the problem. I haven't had time to isolate what part of the imported scheme fixed it. I'll post the imported scheme here for others

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by importing this theme. There is no doubts a single line in this scheme that resolves it but I haven't had a chance to work through which one fixes it (`OTHER_INDENT_OPTIONS` is an obvious candidate for which group).

```
<code_scheme name="Default (1)">
  <option name="OTHER_INDENT_OPTIONS">
    <value>
      <option name="INDENT_SIZE" value="2" />
      <option name="CONTINUATION_INDENT_SIZE" value="8" />
      <option name="TAB_SIZE" value="2" />
      <option name="USE_TAB_CHARACTER" value="false" />
      <option name="SMART_TABS" value="false" />
      <option name="LABEL_INDENT_SIZE" value="0" />
      <option name="LABEL_INDENT_ABSOLUTE" value="false" />
      <option name="USE_RELATIVE_INDENTS" value="false" />
    </value>
  </option>
  <option name="HTML_KEEP_WHITESPACES" value="true" />
  <JSCodeStyleSettings>
    <option name="USE_SEMICOLON_AFTER_STATEMENT" value="false" />
    <option name="FORCE_SEMICOLON_STYLE" value="true" />
    <option name="USE_DOUBLE_QUOTES" value="false" />
    <option name="FORCE_QUOTE_STYlE" value="true" />
    <option name="SPACES_WITHIN_IMPORTS" value="true" />
  </JSCodeStyleSettings>
  <MarkdownNavigatorCodeStyleSettings>
    <option name="RIGHT_MARGIN" value="72" />
  </MarkdownNavigatorCodeStyleSettings>
  <XML>
    <option name="XML_LEGACY_SETTINGS_IMPORTED" value="true" />
  </XML>
  <codeStyleSettings language="HTML">
    <indentOptions>
      <option name="INDENT_SIZE" value="2" />
      <option name="TAB_SIZE" value="2" />
      <option name="SMART_TABS" value="true" />
    </indentOptions>
  </codeStyleSettings>
  <codeStyleSettings language="JavaScript">
    <option name="KEEP_BLANK_LINES_IN_CODE" value="1" />
    <option name="SPACE_BEFORE_METHOD_PARENTHESES" value="true" />
    <option name="TERNARY_OPERATION_SIGNS_ON_NEXT_LINE" value="true" />
    <option name="KEEP_SIMPLE_BLOCKS_IN_ONE_LINE" value="true" />
    <option name="KEEP_SIMPLE_METHODS_IN_ONE_LINE" value="true" />
    <indentOptions>
      <option name="INDENT_SIZE" value="2" />
      <option name="CONTINUATION_INDENT_SIZE" value="2" />
      <option name="TAB_SIZE" value="2" />
    </indentOptions>
  </codeStyleSettings>
  <codeStyleSettings language="ruby">
    <option name="ALIGN_GROUP_FIELD_DECLARATIONS" value="true" />
    <option name="SPACE_WITHIN_BRACES" value="true" />
    <option name="SPACE_WITHIN_ARRAY_INITIALIZER_BRACES" value="true" />
    <indentOptions>
      <option name="CONTINUATION_INDENT_SIZE" value="2" />
    </indentOptions>
  </codeStyleSettings>
</code_scheme>
```